# Behat + Selenium2 Webdriver + PhantomJS: empty HTML

Tags: symfony, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, travis-ci, behat

I am trying to set up testing suite for planned ajax-heavy symfony2-based website. I have set up behat with phantomjs webdriver using selenium2 interface to run tests and **they are working for me locally** without any problems. They **always fail on Travis** though, so I set up *@AfterStep* hook in behat context that prints HTML returned from page and this is what it outputs:

```
string(26) "<head></head><body></body>"
```

If anyone could take a look what I might have borked here's PR from branch I'm working on this: https://github.com/JarJak/memy/pull/3 and the last failing build: https://travis-ci.org/JarJak/memy/builds/77665637

Thanks!

Comment: How did you solve this problem in the end? I'm having a very similar issue :)

Comment: I was able to solve my issue. I don't know if this will help for you but my problem was related to phantomjs attempting to connect to ``localhost`` rather than ``127.0.0.1``. I changed the value of the ``extensions.Behat\MinkExtension.base_url`` option in ``behat.yml``.